# How make dataclass for partial update(Patch method)?

Tags: python, django, rest, python-dataclasses, http-patch

Use @dataclass in my project.
Now I want to implement @dataclass for PATCH method(partial_update) and initialize only provided arguments.

For example:

```
@dataclass
class Person:
    id: int
    first_name: Optional[str]
    last_name: Optional[str]
    birthday: Optional[datetime.date]
```

and use it like:

```
person = Person(id=1, first_name ='Andrew')
```

so now person have only two arguments id and first_name(`person.id, person.first_name` )

Does someone have understanding how to implement such stuff? maybe is some wrapper for @dataclass?

P.S. Can't use

```
@dataclass
class Person:
    id: int
    first_name: Optional[str] = None
    last_name: Optional[str] = None
    birthday: Optional[datetime.date] = None
```

because it will provide None to not provided arguments and it will update fields in database with None.

I don't want these fields be updated in database, so I don't need them being initialized in dataclass.

Comment: Is a `Person` allowed to have `None` for any of these values, or does an instance of `Person` only represent a modification of a person, not the person itself?

Comment: I suspect you are looking for `functools.partial`, but I am not sure if you should have separate `Person` (all fields required) and `PersonUpdate` (any field is optional) classes.

Comment: Or, if what you really want is a `dict` that just *lacks* certain keys to construct the `PATCH` request. (Compare `{'first_name': 'bob'}` with a `Person` object that will have all four attributes no matter what value you assign to them.)

Comment: it represents modification

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check out [`dataclass-wizard`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/), to see if it can work for your use case. It supports [`skip_defaults`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#skip-defaults) argument when serializing a dataclass instance to JSON using `to_dict`, which behaves very similar to the builtin [`dataclasses.asdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict).

You can use `to_dict()` method when saving modified fields (only values passed in to the `__init__()` constructor method) to database, as shown below.

> *Disclaimer*: I am the creator and maintener of this library.

```py
# Can be removed in Python 3.10+, as `X | Y` annotation syntax is supported OOTB
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import date

from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard


@dataclass
class Person(JSONWizard):

    # Custom config for (de)serializing a dataclass instance
    class _(JSONWizard.Meta):
        skip_defaults = True
        # optional: if you need (serialized) field names to be `snake_cased`
        # key_transform_with_dump = 'SNAKE'

    # REQUIRED
    id: int
    # (NOT) REQUIRED
    first_name: str | None = None
    last_name: str | None = None
    birthday: date | None = None


person = Person(id=1, first_name='Andrew')

# Print the `__repr__()` of class instance
print(repr(person))
print()

# Print the update data (for database)
print(person.to_dict())
```

Prints:

```
Person(id=1, first_name='Andrew', last_name=None, birthday=None)

{'id': 1, 'firstName': 'Andrew'}
```